# I have a local json file and i want to display its data in listbox

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

Suppose I have following data in the json file and I want it to render in the same format in my control list box which is in my view file

```
{
"data" :[
  {
       "text" : "abc"
  }
]
}
```

Comment: In [SAPUI5 Listbox](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/ListBox.html) documentation they give an example with explicit creation of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to elaborate and maybe read a little, although something like this shows how you can get data out of the JSON response.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $.getJSON( "http://yourserver/test.json", function( data ) {
        alert (data["data"][0]["text"]);
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If you jQuery or something similar there are plenty of tools to Parse and manipulate the JSON data.

The jQuery Docs should provide you with everything you need to know.  If you are using PHP or something else there a tools for that too.

[jQuery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.stringify() function which convert your object into string

```
var $data={
    "data" :[
      {
           "text" : "abc"
      }
    ]
    } 

    var $str=JSON.stringify($data);
```

now assign $str string wherever you want

Comment: With `JSON.stringify($data, null, 2)` you'll even get pretty printed JSON